# Delete Entire row for empty cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete every row that has empty cell for specific column which happen to be the first column in my sheet. I ran this code :

```
For Y = 2 To 50000
If IsEmpty(Cells(Y, 1)) = True Then
    Rows(Y).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next Y
```

However, nothing changed. Did I get the code wrong somehow ?

Comment: One thing is you need to delete backwards if you intend to do a loop like this.

Comment: If your code is looking at the right sheet, `If IsEmpty(Cells(Y, 1)) Then` instead of what you have. The default test is `True` which your statement will provide (`If True Then`)

Comment: First thank you urdearboy for responding. I used step -1 and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change sheet name on line 3 to your sheet. This has a dynamic loop (it will loop from `A2` to last used row in `Column A`) and round up the rows to-be-deleted. Once the loop is complete, it will delete all rows at once.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteMe()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SearchRange As Range, CurrentCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each CurrentCell In SearchRange
    If CurrentCell = "" Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = CurrentCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, CurrentCell)
        End If
    End If
Next CurrentCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: there's this mismatch error at this line: Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ... I figure it is the word Row so, I changed it to Rows. Then, I after I ran it, nothing happended to the cells

Comment: Perfect, worked like charm. Another question: what if my cells have value of -1 ? how do I delete the entire row ?

Comment: `If CurrentCell = "" Or CurrentCell < 0 Then` will look for both criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
Sub deletecells()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim SearchRange As Range, CurrentCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

ws.Range(SearchRange.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.delete
End Sub
```

Please let me know if your requirement is different.

Thanks